# Proof that in an integral domain every prime element is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, integral-domain

So I'm trying to prove that in an integral domain every prime element is irreducible.

Let's suppose that $p$ is an element in my integral domain.

So now I can study $ p=ab $ (if is not in this form, $p=a*1 $ and this is an irreducible element).

1. $ p $ divides itself so p|p so $ p=ab.$
2. $p|a $ or p|b (because p is prime) and now, WLOG let's suppose that p|a.
3. If $p|a $ need to exist an element $ q $ such that $a=pq.$
4. I can multiply both sides with $ b $ so $ p=pqb.$
5. $p(1-qb)=0 $ so $ qb=1$  (this is true because we are working in an integrity domain and if $ a*b=0 $ a needs to be $0 $ or $ b$  needs to be $0$) and now I can say that b is a unit and $ p=ab $ is an irreducible element.

My question is, why b needs to be a unit element of my domain? Cannot be an invertible element? Like $4*(1/4)$=1 in $\mathbb{Q}$. And if $ b$  can be an invertible element, why does that mean that $ p $ is irreducible?

Sorry for my english, any help would be appreciated! By the way, I'm using Artin's book and $ a $ in $ R $ where $  R$  is a ring is an irreducible element if is not a unit and if it has no proper divisors.

Comment: Is $\frac{1}{4} \in \mathbb{Z} $  true ? $p$ is irreducible in $R$ if $p$ can't be expressed as a product of two non zero non unit elements OF $R$.

Comment: No sorry, made a mistake, already edited.

Comment: Try to read the definition of unit given in your book.  $ a $ is unit if $a$ is Invertible i.e $a$ has multiplicative inverse. And $\frac{1}{4} $ is unit in $\Bbb{Q}$

Comment: Yeah, you're right, Artin says that the element that has multiplicative inverse are units (page 412). Thank you so much!

Comment: prime $\,p = ab\Rightarrow p\mid a\,$ or $\,b.\,$ If $\,p\mid a\,$ then cancelling $p\,\Rightarrow\, 1 = (a/p)b\,$ so $\,b\,$ is a unit. By symmetry $\,p\mid b\,\Rightarrow\, a\,$ is a unit. Thus $p$ is irreducible *by definition*, i.e. if $\,p = ab\,$ then $a$ or $b$ is a unit. See the Theorem in the dupe for a proof that makes the inference clearer.

Comment: A unit in $R$ is an element invertible in $R$ i.e. a divisor of $1$ in $R$, so $1 = qb,\ q\in R\,$ means $b$ is a unit (with inverse $q).\ $ Maybe you are confusing "**a** unit"  with "**the** unit" (neutral element for multiplication, usually denoted $1)\ \ $

Comment: Yes, I was confusing the additive or multiplicative unit of an element in a field (intuitively, I was thinking 1 in $\mathbb{Z}$) with the definition of a generically unit in Artin's book. Thanks!